# Changing the color of a background with highcharts.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

I’m trying to change the background colors of a highcharts scatter plot. I can easily change the color of the section with this code below. However, I need change the background to more than one color. Essentially I’m trying shade the area from 60-100 with dark gray and also color the area 100-120 with light gray and than 40-60 with light gray. This is going to be a confidence plot, so I feel as if this is a feature that should be fairly common but I cannot find a solution.

this code adds a light gray background to the plot..

```
 plotBands: [{
       from: 60,
       to: 100,
       color: '#d9d9d9'
    }]
```

Fiddle: [Fiddle Here...](http://jsfiddle.net/osevj9m3/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just pass another object to plotBands array:
Updatated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/osevj9m3/1/

```
plotBands: [{
  from: 60,
  to: 100,
  color: '#d9d9d9'
}, 
{
  from: 100,
  to: 120,
  color: '#333'
}]
```

Comment: Thank you! exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Simply modify your plotBands to be

```
    plotBands: [{
        from: 60,
        to: 100,
        color: '#d9d9d9'
    },{
        from: 40,
        to: 10,
        color: '#d0d9d9'
    }],
```

Thanks,
-K